# NRI Travelling to Europe from Home Country

Tags: visas, schengen, visa-refusals, europe, italy

I am an Non Resident Indian. I am currently on vacation in India. My parents are traveling from India to Europe and I would like to travel to Europe with them.

Is it possible to apply for a Schengen Visa from India, rather than my country of residence?

Yes I am basically applying for visa in Italian Embassy because i will be staying there most of the days compared to other countries.(I will be going to 5 countries in 15 days trip) So NRI is a person who is an Indian Citizen holding Indian Passport but working in other country, I have been working there since last three years. Yes I am in fear of visa rejection, because my trip planner and few others told me that I need to be working atleast last 6 months in a country where i am applying from. But According to what I have read in Schengen visa official website if a Indian passport holder resides elsewhere, if he is legally present while applying the visa and gives justification, he can apply. But my worry is visa getting rejected. I have heard a new biometric system is established recently so not many people know of this rule. I also called up Italian Embassy mumbai customer care to clarify about this. He was like you can apply if your birth place is in India. The main problem is I have already booked tickets to go to India from where i am residing now next week, so applying for visa here is impossible now.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Travel.SE! Can you please clarify what is an NRI in the question? I see you added the tags 'italy' and 'visa-refusals', are you travelling to Italy, and if you have actually been refused a visa or in fear or being refused one?

Comment: @Sharat Naik If you’re planning on travelling to anywhere in the Schengen area, it is normally obligatory to apply for a visa from your country of residence. Non Schengen European countries have different requirements eg for the U.K. it’s typically possible to apply from any location where there’s an embassy or processing centre. You’ll get a better answer if you expand your question to be more specific, as @ B.Liu has said

Comment: Already the embassy said you can apply and it's impossible for us to tell whether you'll be refused. (And it's too old now anyways.)